# Angular module not available in Karma Jasmine test run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using angular full stack for development, my karma.conf.js file is

```
files: [             
    'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js',
    'app/scripts/controllers/*.js',
    'app/scripts/directives/*.js',
    'app/scripts/services/*.js',
    'app/scripts/app.js',
    'lib/routes.js',           
    'test/karma/unit/**/test.spec.js'      
],
```

Test Spec:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
describe('App', function() {

    describe('TestController', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            this.addMatchers({
                toEqualData: function(expected) {
                    return angular.equals(this.actual, expected);
                }
            });
        });

        // Load the controllers module
        beforeEach(module('ratefastApp'));

        // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
        var TestController,
            mockUserResource,
            scope,
            $httpBackend,
            $routeParams,
            $location;

        // The injector ignores leading and trailing underscores here (i.e. _$httpBackend_).
        // This allows us to inject a service but then attach it to a variable
        // with the same name as the service.

        beforeEach(
            inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$location_, _$routeParams_, _$httpBackend_) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            TestController = $controller('TestController', {
                $scope: scope
            });
            $routeParams = _$routeParams_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/test/page/:pagenum')
                .respond([{title: 'test'}]);
            $location = _$location_;

        }));
    });
});
});
```

On running the above I'm getting `$injector:nomod Module is not available`.

Answer (score 48):

The module(s) needs to be loaded in your karma files before the rest of the application.

This is because "Calling angular.module without the array of dependencies when the module has not yet been defined causes this error to be thrown" [docs.angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod). Therefore, you must explicitly load the files before the rest of your application.

In your Karma.config javascript files:

```
    'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario.js',

    'app/scripts/app.js',        // Load your module before the rest of your app.

    'app/scripts/controllers/*.js',
    'app/scripts/directives/*.js',
    'app/scripts/services/*.js',
    'lib/routes.js',           
    'test/karma/unit/**/test.spec.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that some module is not being found.  Specifically the [source for loader.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/loader.js/#LC92) seems to show that this error gets thrown when you haven't registered a module with `angular.module`.  Have you done so with `ratefastApp`?  Here's the copied source:

```
    if (!requires) {
      throw $injectorMinErr('nomod', "Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled " +
         "the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you " +
         "specify the dependencies as the second argument.", name);
    }
```

Also, Since you are trying to inject `$controller, $rootScope, _$location_, _$routeParams_, _$httpBackend_`, with the mock [$inject](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject), I'd start by ensuring you have the files containing those services in your karma.conf.js `files` directive. You may also want to use wildcards to include all angular files.