# Gulp test can not find module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I generated my web application with [gulp angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular). Then I created a service and want to test it.

Module file is app.module.js

```
angular.module('text', []);
```

Service file is text.service.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('text')
    .factory('description',TextService);

  TextService.$inject = ['$http']

  function TextService($http) {

    return {
      QueryStaticText: queryStaticText

  };

    function queryStaticText(link) {
      return link;
    }
  }

})();
```

Test file is text.service.spec.js

```
'use strict';

describe('TextService', function () {
  var description;

  beforeEach(function () {

    module('text');

    inject(function (_description_) {
      description = _description_;
    });

  });

  it('should return text', function () {
    expect(description.QueryStaticText("Hello")).toEqual("Hello anu");
  });
});
```

In the console I execute gulp test and I've got the error message

```
[22:02:44] Using gulpfile /Volumes/Developer/angularjs/project/gulpfile.js
[22:02:44] Starting 'test'...
[22:02:45] Starting Karma server...
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket 1KW_uYCk45moVKwfgAd2 with id 19804685
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) ERROR
  Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'text' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/nomod?p0=text
  at /Volumes/Developer/angularjs/project/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1769



/Volumes/Developer/angularjs/project/gulp/unit-tests.js:30
      throw err;
```

The text module is not loaded, how can I load it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not loading your files in order in Karma.  Inside of you karma.conf.js there should be a file list. Load the app module then the rest of your javascript. Here is a post that had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700615/angular-module-not-available-in-karma-jasmine-test-run/26727453#26727453).

For Example:

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',

  'app/**/*.module.js',  // Loads all files with .module.js
  'app/**/*.js',         // Load the rest of your .js angular files
  'test/**/*.js'         // Load your tests
],
```

Comment: I will try it and will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Use `angularFilesort` to order files by dependency:

```
// gulp/unit-tests.js
...
// around line 36 inserted the following line:
.pipe($.angularFilesort())
```

So should look like:

```
gulp.src(srcFiles)
  .pipe($.angularFilesort())
  .pipe(concat(function(files) {
    callback(bowerDeps.js
      .concat(_.pluck(files, 'path'))
      .concat(htmlFiles)
      .concat(specFiles));
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeEach(module('text'));
beforeEach(inject(function (_description_) {
  description = _description_;
}));
```

Basically, the return value of your module and injection need to be the argument for `beforeEach`.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#unit-testing

Comment: I try it, but does not help anything. Details description https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues/364#issuecomment-75015636