# Grunt-Karma-Jasmine: can not find module

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, gruntfile

I am trying to set up tests for my Angular.js project and I keep getting "$injector:nomod, Module 'result' is not available! You either misspelled..." error. I am sure that I am including "result" module in the "files" array inside "karma.config.js", basically it looks like this:

```
files: [
          '../javascripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js',
          '../jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
          '../D3/d3.js',
          'libs/angular.min.js',
          'libs/angular-route.min.js',
          'libs/angular-animate.min.js',
          'libs/selectize.js',
          'libs/angular-selectize.js',
          'libs/angular-mocks.js',

          'simulator.js',

          '*.js',
          'services/**/*.js',
          'qa/tests-*.js'
],
```

...

I thought initially that the ordering of the main module: 'simulator' (defined inside 'simulator.js' file) is wrong, so I specifically moved it upwards, before
the other modules, like the following stackoverflow thread recommends:

[Angular module not available in Karma Jasmine test run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700615/angular-module-not-available-in-karma-jasmine-test-run)

It did not help. Then I tried to make sure that the files are imported in the same order as in my angular apps' main entry file (except for angular-mocks.js and qa/tests-*.js), importing each single file, instead of using wildcards, but no success.

Jasmine definitely goes inside the test files but stumbles upon the line where I am trying to import the module "result":

```
describe('simulator.chartService', function() {

var chartService;
var graphConfig;

console.log("instantiating module result");
  beforeEach(module('result'));
console.log("finished instantiating");

beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
  graphConfig = $injector.get('graphConfig');
  chartService = $injector.get('chartService');

}));

it('should be created', function() {
  expect(chartService.calcColors(10)).not.toBeNull();
});

});
```

So, I see that the error happens in-between two console.log() statements.

I suspect that still something can be wrong with the ordering of my files inside the array "files" in "karma.config.js". I have main module "simulator" which is dependent on other modules:

```
angular.module('simulator', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','selectize','newexp2','newexp','login','edit','exps', 'result','templates','commons'])
```

Modules 'newexp2', 'newexp', 'login', 'edit', 'exps', 'result', 'templates' are all dependent on the module 'commons'.

How to correctly import interdependent modules inside the "files" array?
Is it just enough to place "simulator.js", main module, above all others,
or I also need to place all other modules before "commons.js"?

Another my suspicion is that angular.js library version that I downloaded from the official angular website, "angular-mocks.js", can be incompatible with other modules that I am using. I had such an issue with "angular-animate.js" file before.

As long as I surround my test code with `$(function(){...})` (and all other my modules ARE surrounded with it) it does not generate the error while importing the `result` module, so I start seeing two `console.log()` statements without an error in-between, however, this generates some unknown error which prevents me from invoking the `it` part at all, whereas when I do not surround it with `$(function(){...})`, the `it` test is invoked, but the module `result` import fails.

So far I am pretty much stuck and do not know where to move and what to try. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `simulator` is the missing module? Maybe it is one of the other modules you are injecting.

Comment: no, it is not missing according to the error it is giving me. The 'result' module which main module 'simulator' is dependent on is missing

Comment: I am running `grunt` in terminal, it shows there an error b/w two `console.log()` statements. I follow the link with the error and it shows the following `$injector:modulerr`: `Failed to instantiate module result due to:
[$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=result
I/<@http://localhost:9876//home/nikita/workspace/simulator/public/angular/libs/angular.min.js?b6b56d0e096efc26e09d6cf2cd37aac6123cc346:6:416
de/workFn@http://localhost:9876/base/libs/angular-mocks.js?e...` Following the link further gives me `$injector:nomod`: `Module 'result' is not available! ...`

Comment: Where are you defining the `result` module?

Comment: in the `result.js` file which is in the same folder with `karma.config.js` file, so I can either import it manually, same way as I am doing with `simulator.js`, or specify it with the wildcard: `*.js` which is what I am doing right away after the `simulator.js` file is imported.

Comment: neither one (manual, wildcard) importing is working, of course. Inside result.js I have: `$(function(){
angular.module('result', ['commons'])
 ...`

Comment: I should also point out that the application itself is working just fine, so in the main file, simulator.js, I am able to import all of the modules by `angular.module('simulator', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','selectize','newexp2','newexp','login','edit', 'exps', 'result','templates','commons'])`

Comment: Another thing that I just noticed is that if I wrap my test file in `$(function(){...});`, then somehow two `console.log()` statements are shown and no module error is generated: it stops moving anywhere further, not even invoking the `it` part. In console I start seeing that it just fails without any explanations. Without wrapping, it invokes the `it` part and any `console.log()` in-between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The issue was that ALL of my angular code was enclosed inside `$(function(){...})`. The solution is to remove all of the `$function(){...})`, then reorder javascript imports inside the main entry .html file, and then all of the testing starts working good. 
The question might be better to mark as duplicate with:

[Angular document.ready() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490048/angular-document-ready-issue)