# Karma config can't find files

Tags: angularjs, gulp, karma-jasmine

I'm messing around with karma and can't my files to load. I added a files array to karma.config.js and I just see this error for all the modules: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'loginModule' is not available!

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(config) {

  config.set({
    autoWatch : false,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

    plugins : [
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine'
    ],

    files: [
       './app/index.js',
       './app/**/*.js',
       './components/**/*.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

// login.module.js

```
angular.module('loginModule', []);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular module not available in Karma Jasmine test run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700615/angular-module-not-available-in-karma-jasmine-test-run)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify the base as a property within the config:

```
base: '/'
```

or

```
base: __dirname
```

Or whatever points to the assumed root.

Also,
Make sure to load your module files first. If all your module file definitions end with .module.js, do this:

```
files: [
  './app/index.js',
  './app/**/*.module.js',
  './app/**/*.js',
  './components/**/*.js'
]
```

It's very likely that you are trying to use the module in another file before it is defined.